# GTA V started crashing with error 0xc0000005 STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION after Casino/Rockstar Launcher updates

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v

Ever since the Diamond Casino and Rockstar Launcher updates happened, GTA V has started to crash inconsistently every time I play. Sometimes I can play for 30 minutes, sometimes maybe 4 hours or more.

Then at some point the game closes to desktop saying "Grand Theft Auto V exited unexpectedly"

The launcher.log shows this:

```
[2019-10-14 23:48:04.621] [DISPLAY] [ 9620] [gamelaunch] Game exited with code 0xc0000005 (3221225477)
[2019-10-14 23:48:04.622] [ ERROR ] [ 9620] [crashdetection] Exit code 0xc0000005 indicates a fatal game exit (reason: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
```

I googled for it and found out that there are others suffering from the same problem (including my gaming friends). Unfortunately I did not find any solution that would work for me.

I tried clean install on another PC (different specs and such, eliminates most of the individual PC related reasons) with default install settings. I also tried to verify game files, everything checked OK. (Steam version of the game)

The issue still persisted so this should mean that the origin of the crash lies in the game files or Rockstar servers.

Some people blamed NVIDIA, but some of crashing players have AMD GPU's, so NVIDIA drivers shouldn't be the case here.

Even if there is no solution anywhere so far, does anyone know the reason for this crash? I have not seen any information from Rockstar announcing this error or trying to patch it.

EDIT: Also, I've send a ticket to Rockstar support, and they asked for my launcher.log file, which I sent to them, but they have not replied anything after that.

EDIT: I checked the "Hibernate when running a game" option in Rockstar Launcher, then I played few hours OK, after I close the game normally without errors, the launcher gave an **error with code 7002.1** which according to Google results, refers to the bug that prevents people from playing offline. Which is confusing since I play online all the time.

I dont know if the "hibernate" option fixed the crashing, I need to play more and longer sessions to confirm.

EDIT: The hibernation did not fix the crash, though it might have prolonged it a bit. I can now play a little longer, but the crash happens still.
I strongly believe that Rockstar messed something up with the Casino/Rockstar Launcher updates and that error causes some kind of permission violation with Windows. STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION sounds like some kind of security related thing.

EDIT: OK, looks like at least Nvidia has acknowledged the problem and is currently investigating the issue with Rockstar, according to the latest Nvidia driver release notes.

Comment: This error appears to be a missing library, have you tried installing the latest 32-bit and 64-bit Visual C++ 2015 and 2017 redistributables?

Comment: @HugoZink Where did that info come from? No, I have not tried such a thing yet.

Comment: I happen to know this particular error code. Usually it means a missing redistributable. You can check the game folder for any redistributables, otherwise manually reinstalling the Visual C++ 2013, 2015, and 2017 redistributables from Microsoft should be enough.

Comment: @HugoZink It did not help. The game crashed again after reinstalling all those redistributales.

Comment: FYI the error is from, for example, an uninitialized pointer and it is going to be the fault of the program. It has nothing to do with security permissions. see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796200/

Comment: @Yorik OK, but anyway that kind of problem should be still from Rockstar messing with the code somehow. It seems that there is nothing else to do but wait for a patch from Rockstar or some other involved company. Nvidia just released new drivers but they did not help.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue after the rockstar launcher update, I've tried deleting configs, fresh game install, lowering settings, rolling back drivers, fresh windows installs, safe mode, turning off all startup items, giving the exes admin access, launching from the GTALauncher exe with steam exited. Pretty much anything you can think of I've tried.

The only solutions I've find to somewhat help are rolling back nvidia drivers to 431.86 (studio driver). The errors would be every 1-3 hours instead of every 15-30 min. Deleting the config also prolonged it a bit, but not enough to make it worth rebuilding your settings each time.

Pretty sure this is on rockstar's side, the game ran fine even after the casino update, but I'm guessing the launcher is messing with permissions. Hopeful they allow you to run the game without the launcher soon.